# Dynamic select values in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, nette

I have form for searching through products that encapsulates three selects: material, weight, and color. These selects contain values from database.

I would like to have a following behavior:

- If user selects material, the remaining two selects will display only values that are acceptable for products with a given material
- Apply this to all three selects vice versa

Before I started with nette, I had been doing this using ajax and jquery/javascript by dynamically changing select elements, after user selected value in other select.

I believe in nette should be some good (system) solution, how to reload select's values in a corresponding presenter. Can you help me please?

Comment: Before you started with nette, you also had some kind of backend functionality for generating filtered option lists, didn't you? You will at least have to use still *few* JavaScript for triggering actions on select events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look into the documentation of nette. In my opinion, this is what you are searching for: http://pla.nette.org/en/dependent-form-select-with-ajax

You can write handles for select changes, and in those handles load to form remaining selects. No messy work with javascript.